# Creating Promises in loop and break the loop as some resolved condition occur

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm writing a crawler. The task is to scan in worst case 10 pages. I can happen that I only need to scan 1 page but this depends on page content. If there is no item that I'm looking for on first page then we are moving to second page until we reach 10 page. We are not interested in page 11 and more. So we have a limit. I would like to invoke request for page 1 and if item is found then break for loop and resolve Promise.

Pseudocode:

```
func findItem(item: Item): Promise<PageIndex> {
    for (let page=1; page<=10; page++) {
        create url with page as url
        create promise that request url and resolve to content as content
        if content contains item {
            return Promise.resolve(page); // We are interesting in on which page the item is.
            // Here we are breaking loop and exit function because we
            // Found what we were looking for
        }
        // continue to next page because content does not contain item on this page
    }
    // We didnt find item on first 10 pages
    return Promise.resolve(-1)
}
```

So I don't know how to implement this using Native Promises and Typescript. Im aware how Promises work in general and I was using them many times but this use case is new for me. Anyone can help?

Comment: Use either recursion or `async`/`await` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two functions (maybe three), one for requesting a page (Let's aptly name it `requestPage()`, I will not show how you should implement it, as it should be fairly obvious) and returning the parsed result (that might be another function, depending on your parsing needs), and the orchestrator (the loop you have in your pseudo-code).

The trick here is that your orchestrator should be an `async` function.

```
async function findItem(item: Item) {
  for (let page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
    const contents = await requestPage(page);
    if (contents.include('whateverYouAreInterestedIn')) {
      return page;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Note how closely this resembles synchronous looking code. The interesting bits are the `async` I added before the `function` keyword, and the `await` I added before the Promise returned by `requestPage(page)`.

Also, as an addendum, TypeScript can generally infer the return type of functions (even async functions), so it's *almost* never needed to be explicit about the return type.

---

It's worth noting that it *is* possible to implement without the use of async function, with a clever use of chaining `.then()`s and a semi-recursive function, but it's far less readable in my opinion than a simple async function with a clear loop.

Comment: Thank You Very much. Its working with async await. It was new to me but I read about it and it fits nicely.